# How many decimal places to give exact result

Tags: math, rounding, precision

Let's assume I have two decimal numbers a and b, each with two decimal places. I would now like to determine a factor x which, multiplied by a, gives b. This is x = b / a

Is there any way of calculating the minimum number of decimal places required for the result of b = a * x to be exact to two decimal places (without rounding)?

Example:

```
a = 76,33
b = 44,12 

x1 = 0,5780165072710599 (16 decimal places)
b1 = 76,33 * 0,5780165072710599
b1 = 44,120000000000002167

x2 = 0,578016507271059 (15 decimal places)
b2 = 76,33 * 0,578016507271059
b2 = 44,11999999999993347

x3 = 0,57801650727106 (14 decimal places; rounded)
b3 = 76,33 * 0,57801650727106
b3 = 44,1200000000000098

x4 = 0,5780 (4 decimal places; rounded like GAAP)
b4 = 76,33 * 0,5780
b4 = 44,11874

x5 = 0,5781 (4 decimal places; corrected, not rounded)
b5 = 76,33 * 0,5781
b5 = 44,126373‬ (it's 44,12* now, but far more away from 44,120 than the previous 44,11874)
```

Four decimal places are recommended by the "Generally Accepted Accounting Principles (GAAP)" to counteract rounding errors. In my case, however, I find that this leads to significant rounding problems when summing and multiplying large amounts.

Take for example b4 = 44,11874 and now book 1.000.000 times this position. You end up with 44.118.740. With b1 = 44,120000000000002167 the sum would be 44.120.000. The difference would already be 1.260, which would already make a difference for a currency amount.

Is it possible to calculate the minimum number of decimal places required to be on the safe side?

Comment: If you want exactness, just use integers. Depending on what language you're using, your a and b probably aren't even stored exactly to 2 decimal places. COBOL for example, does use fixed point decimals which can hold such numbers exactly, and you can add and subtract exactly, but multiplication and especially division can cause rounding issues. Most newer languages use floating point decimals which can't store numbers like 0.01 exactly.

Comment: There is no "safe side". Theoretically, once you drop even only one decimal digit, you will get differences on summing up enough values.  You may be able to push the limits, but if the numbers grow large enough, errors are inevitable. And practically (ie in any computer system) you are bound by the precision of the floating point arithmetics ....

Comment: Python has both [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) and [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) modules that you might find interesting.

Comment: Generally if x = b / a is the true math equation, but instead of x you have x' = x + e with an error e, then you'll get b' = a x' = a x + a e = b + a e. So if you want the error on b' to be at most 1/200 (so b' rounds to b at two decimal places) then you need the error on x' to be at most 1/(200 a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following exact math equation:

```
x = b / a
```

However when you round `x`, you end up with:

```
x' = x + e
```

where `e` is an error term.

If you round `x` to k decimal places, then `e` is going to be between -1/(2 10^k) and +1/(k 10^k). For instance if you round `x` to 4 decimal places, then `e` is going to be between -0.00005 and +0.00005.

Then when you try to recompute `b` using `x'` instead of `x`, you get a value `b'` which also has an error term:

```
b' = a x' = a x + a e = b + a e
```

The error term on `b'` is now `a e`.

So if you want the error term on `b'` to be at most 1 / 200, so that `b'` rounds to `b` at two decimal places, then you need the error term on `x'` to be at most 1 / (200 a).

In most of your examples, `a` was always less than 100, so rounding to 4 decimal places was good.

But in your last example, `a` is 1000000, so you need 8 decimal places for `x`.